# Upload images from pasted images in gutenberg wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

When I'm going to paste images in the block editor they uploaded to host without any touch.
I don't want it, I want to disable this feature. it just uploaded with address called image.png

I didn't find any solution for this issue. Do I have to disable block editor?